# Pygame is crashing everytime the "update_score" function is called, why?

Tags: python, function, pygame

So I noticed that in my pygame code below, when I run a function called update_score, which keeps track of whenever the beamrect.x == 0 (it hits the end of the screen), pygame just crashes without even raising an error. I experimented and found out that pygame only crashes when I call the function. Why is it doing that?

```
# Your header should go here, each comment should be initialed -DK
import pygame 
import sys
import os

# https://youtu.be/jO6qQDNa2UY

pygame.init()
FPS = 60

# Useful Variables
  # Size
size = height, width = 900, 500
zonhw = zheight, zwidth = 70, 70
scale2 = height2, width2 = 200, 300
lscale = lheight, lwidth = 80, 80
beamsz = bheight, bwidth = 15,25
platz = pheight, pwidth = 10, 70
ground = 10, 900
score = 1
life = 3
  # RGB 
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0, 0, 128)
green = (0, 255, 0)
brown = (165,42,42)
  # Speed
VEL = 5
beamspeed = 3
  # Position
laserpos = posx, posy = 500,250
  #other
i = 0



# graphics
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Zonic bootleg")
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
zonic = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","zonic.gif"))
zonic = pygame.transform.scale(zonic, zonhw)
bg =  pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","sonic-back.jpg"))
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, size)
gg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","gg.jpg"))
gg= pygame.transform.scale(gg, size)
lazerz = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","Lazerz.gif"))
lazerz = pygame.transform.scale(lazerz, lscale)
beam = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","laserbeam.jpg"))
beam = pygame.transform.scale(beam, beamsz)
lives = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","health.png"))
lives = pygame.transform.scale(lives,(30,30))
zoncz = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","zoncz.png"))
zoncz = pygame.transform.scale(zoncz, scale2)




#coalitions 
# NOTE on ERROR - when you modify a parameter, it makes a local copy but doesn't change 
# the global variable...  either you update the global variable or return the updated
# value back
def collider(lifeParam,beamrect,zonicrect,lazerect):
  global life   
  beamrect.x -= beamspeed
  if zonicrect.colliderect(beamrect):
    #print ("Laser Collided with Zonic")
    beamrect.x = lazerect.x+21
    zonicrect.x = 0
    life -= 1
    
  if beamrect.x <-60:
    #screen.blit(beam, (posx, posy))
    beamrect.x += 550


#updating score
def updating_score(beamrect, scoreparam): #<--- this is the function I am talking about
  global score
  svd = font.render(f"Score: {score}", True, black)

  while True:
    if beamrect.x == 0:
      score += 1
      print(score)
    screen.blit(svd, (250, 0))
    pygame.display.update()




#Death
def death():
    while life <= 0:
      

        death = font.render("Gameover lol", True, white)
        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(death, (250, 250))
        pygame.display.update()



  
# zonic movement
def KWS(keyvar, zonicrect,flip):
  
  if keyvar[pygame.K_RIGHT]:  # right
    zonicrect.x += VEL
    flip = False
  if zonicrect.x > 850:
    zonicrect.x -= VEL
    
  if keyvar[pygame.K_LEFT] and zonicrect.x + VEL > 0:  # left
    zonicrect.x -= VEL
    flip = True
  

  
def heart(life):
    x = 1
    i = -25
    while life >= x:
      x +=1 
      i+=25
      screen.blit(lives, (2+i,0))
    # print("life: ", life)

# draw
def drawingfunc(zonicrect,lazerect, beamrect,flip, zonczrect, life):
 
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    heart(life)
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(zonic,flip,False),(zonicrect.x, zonicrect.y))
    screen.blit(beam, (beamrect.x, beamrect.y+15))
    screen.blit(lazerz, (lazerect.x+21,lazerect.y))
    screen.blit(zoncz, (zonczrect.x, zonczrect.y))
    pygame.display.update()





# mainloop and refresh rate
def main():
    jump = False
    jumpCount = 0
    jumpMax = 15
    flip = False
    zonicrect = pygame.Rect(10, 250, zheight, zwidth)
    lazerect = pygame.Rect(posx, posy, lheight, lwidth)
    beamrect = pygame.Rect(posx, posy, bheight, bwidth)
    zonczrect = pygame.Rect(200, 75, height2, width2)
    
    # (30,0,32,32)
    # livesrect = pygame.Rect(0,0,10,10)
    
    
    
      
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if not jump and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                  jump = True
                  jumpCount = jumpMax 
  
        death()
        collider(life,beamrect,zonicrect,lazerect)
        keyspressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        KWS(keyspressed, zonicrect,flip)     
        drawingfunc(zonicrect,lazerect, beamrect,flip, zonczrect, life)
        update_score(beamrect, score)
        if jump:
            zonicrect.y -= jumpCount
            if jumpCount > -jumpMax:                                                              
              jumpCount -= 1                             
            else:
              jump = False

    pygame.quit()                                                              
                                                              

# calling function NOTE: needs to always be at the end of file
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: My guess is that beamrect.x never equals to something other than 0. That is why the loop simply runs forever

Comment: But the end of the left side of screen is x = 0? How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function **every frame**. So put the function inside of your **main while loop**.
So try something like this:

```
# Your header should go here, each comment should be initialed -DK
import pygame 
import sys
import os

# https://youtu.be/jO6qQDNa2UY

pygame.init()
FPS = 60

# Useful Variables
  # Size
size = height, width = 900, 500
zonhw = zheight, zwidth = 70, 70
scale2 = height2, width2 = 200, 300
lscale = lheight, lwidth = 80, 80
beamsz = bheight, bwidth = 15,25
platz = pheight, pwidth = 10, 70
ground = 10, 900
score = 1
life = 3
  # RGB 
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0, 0, 128)
green = (0, 255, 0)
brown = (165,42,42)
  # Speed
VEL = 5
beamspeed = 3
  # Position
laserpos = posx, posy = 500,250
  #other
i = 0



# graphics
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Zonic bootleg")
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
zonic = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","zonic.gif"))
zonic = pygame.transform.scale(zonic, zonhw)
bg =  pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","sonic-back.jpg"))
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, size)
gg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","gg.jpg"))
gg= pygame.transform.scale(gg, size)
lazerz = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","Lazerz.gif"))
lazerz = pygame.transform.scale(lazerz, lscale)
beam = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","laserbeam.jpg"))
beam = pygame.transform.scale(beam, beamsz)
lives = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","health.png"))
lives = pygame.transform.scale(lives,(30,30))
zoncz = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("image","zoncz.png"))
zoncz = pygame.transform.scale(zoncz, scale2)




#coalitions 
# NOTE on ERROR - when you modify a parameter, it makes a local copy but doesn't change 
# the global variable...  either you update the global variable or return the updated
# value back
def collider(lifeParam,beamrect,zonicrect,lazerect):
  global life   
  beamrect.x -= beamspeed
  if zonicrect.colliderect(beamrect):
    #print ("Laser Collided with Zonic")
    beamrect.x = lazerect.x+21
    zonicrect.x = 0
    life -= 1
    
  if beamrect.x <-60:
    #screen.blit(beam, (posx, posy))
    beamrect.x += 550


#updating score
def updating_score(beamrect, score): #<--- this is the function I am talking about
  svd = font.render(f"Score: {score}", True, black)

  if beamrect.x == 0:
      score += 1
      print(score)

  screen.blit(svd, (250, 0))
  pygame.display.update()




#Death
def death():
    while life <= 0:
      

        death = font.render("Gameover lol", True, white)
        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(death, (250, 250))
        pygame.display.update()



  
# zonic movement
def KWS(keyvar, zonicrect,flip):
  
  if keyvar[pygame.K_RIGHT]:  # right
    zonicrect.x += VEL
    flip = False
  if zonicrect.x > 850:
    zonicrect.x -= VEL
    
  if keyvar[pygame.K_LEFT] and zonicrect.x + VEL > 0:  # left
    zonicrect.x -= VEL
    flip = True
  

  
def heart(life):
    x = 1
    i = -25
    while life >= x:
      x +=1 
      i+=25
      screen.blit(lives, (2+i,0))
    # print("life: ", life)

# draw
def drawingfunc(zonicrect,lazerect, beamrect,flip, zonczrect, life):
 
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    heart(life)
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(zonic,flip,False),(zonicrect.x, zonicrect.y))
    screen.blit(beam, (beamrect.x, beamrect.y+15))
    screen.blit(lazerz, (lazerect.x+21,lazerect.y))
    screen.blit(zoncz, (zonczrect.x, zonczrect.y))
    pygame.display.update()





# mainloop and refresh rate
def main():
    jump = False
    jumpCount = 0
    jumpMax = 15
    flip = False
    zonicrect = pygame.Rect(10, 250, zheight, zwidth)
    lazerect = pygame.Rect(posx, posy, lheight, lwidth)
    beamrect = pygame.Rect(posx, posy, bheight, bwidth)
    zonczrect = pygame.Rect(200, 75, height2, width2)
    
    # (30,0,32,32)
    # livesrect = pygame.Rect(0,0,10,10)
    
    
    
      
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if not jump and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                  jump = True
                  jumpCount = jumpMax 
  
        death()
        collider(life,beamrect,zonicrect,lazerect)
        keyspressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        KWS(keyspressed, zonicrect,flip)     
        drawingfunc(zonicrect,lazerect, beamrect,flip, zonczrect, life)
        update_score(beamrect, score)
        if jump:
            zonicrect.y -= jumpCount
            if jumpCount > -jumpMax:                                                              
              jumpCount -= 1                             
            else:
              jump = False

    pygame.quit()                                                              
                                                              

# calling function NOTE: needs to always be at the end of file
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```